# Angular interpolation binding value not loading inside [innerhtml] in angular6

Tags: angular, binding

In `Component.ts`

```
this.innerHtmlValueData  = "<....>{{title}}<...>"
```

In HTML

```
<...[innerHTML]="innerHtmlValueData"></...>
```

I have also tried with `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml` it is still not working. It doesn't show the title value,

Comment: Welcome. Please show more code, some errors from log so that we can help.

Comment: Hi the thing is we have design studio in our application on that we can able to drag and drop components(text box,Form fields etc).

Based on the Design we need to load HTML.
That HTML also contains code like interpolation binding,and many angular fields and directives.
when i try to use [innerHTML] property it is working for normal HTML manipulation(ie using B tag it displays bold content) but it is not working for angular code when try to display title variable value as {{title}} instead of displaying title it displays the raw data as "{{title}}"

Comment: sample Code

var content = "<h1>{{title}</h1>"
<div [innerHTML]="content "></div>

Not only a variable binding we need the support of all the things in angular  like angular property binding,style rendering etc.

Comment: I added question to render HTML by dynamic compiling 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237258/dynamic-template-compilation-in-angular-6

but not get proper solutions

Answer (score 0):

in HTML

```
<div [innerHTML]="innerHtmlValueData"></div>
```

In Component.ts

```
title = "ERP"

innerHtmlValueData  = "<htmltag>"+this.title+"</htmltag>"
```

or

```
innerHtmlValueData:string = `<span class="badge badge-secondary">${this.title}</span>`
```

try this

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer,Please Read my comments on the Question .
we have two separate components one for design and one for preview.on design page the above html (innerHtmlValueData  = "<htmltag>"+this.title+"</htmltag>"
)is binded but the title value reside in preview component so in create comp HTML it will throw error title is undefined

Comment: innerHtmlValueData:string  = `<span class="badge badge-secondary">${this.title}</span>`  use back quote

Comment: you have two separate component then use @viewChildren.  
  https://medium.com/@tkssharma/understanding-viewchildren-viewchild-contentchildren-and-contentchild-b16c9e0358e

Comment: Hi thanks once again!
By using ${this.title} we can bind the value inside [innerHTML].
But not  only bindings we need Angular things like ngFor,ngIf and so On need to work but it will not supported in [innerHTML] ,so how can i solve this,please suggest some ideas.

Comment: Hi, as per my experience and knowledge , use function binding  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzjxtx  i think it's not enough for you but as per my understanding i did this code.

Comment: Your Idea is good for small Set of HTML but we have big content with many ngFor and ngIf configuring each of one is Difficult.

Comment: dividing each part in one component and use it which component you want.  https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding , https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs