# Dynamic Template compilation in Angular 6

Tags: angular

In our application we are rendering the template dynamically since in AngularJS we use  $compile to compile html dynamically  like wise is anything available in angular 6 to compile HTML maually.I searched for but won't get any proper solution please suggest me .Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)

Answer (score 0):

In this [Angular boilerplate](https://github.com/mohammad-haji/ngir/) i crated a dynamic page based on JSON Schema, if you check this module you can learn much about how to dynamically load component and modules( in [NGIR](https://github.com/mohammad-haji/ngir/) is called widgets)

[link to ngx-schema-page of NGIR Project](https://github.com/mohammad-haji/ngir/tree/master/src/app/%40core/ngx-schema-page)

hope is help.